# In Moorcock's Multiverse, is Tiddles the same cat as Whiskers?

Tags: eternal-champion

I'm reading *The English Assassin*, and a small black and white cat makes an appearance at the Peace Conference Ball. Later, it's being carried by Mrs. Cornelius, and called Tiddles. Aside from not having wings, it matches the descriptions of Jhary-a-Conel's cat Whiskers.

Am I right in assuming they're the same cats, or at least, much like there are Eternal Champions and Companions, there's also Cats, and Tiddles is just a manifestation of Whiskers?

Answer (score 1):

#### Outside of the [Eternal Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Champion), the [Companion to Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Champion#Incarnations_of_the_Companion_to_Champions), the [Eternal Consort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Champion#Incarnations_of_the_Eternal_Consort) and [the Black Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormbringer), there are few characters who exist as cross-temporal analogs.

- While they are both cats, there is no reason both Tiddles or Whiskers are remotely significant enough to warrant having an analog in the first place.

Comment: I beg to differ. Keep in mind a few things: (1) Tiddles seems to be the key to Jerry's restoration in both _The English Assassin_ and _The Condition of Muzak_. (2) Whiskers later reappears as the pet of Yarmila in _Elric: The Balance Lost_. I'm inclined to believe the cats are marginally important. There's also Fiarshern in "The Flame Bringers", as well as the cat of Philander Groot (from _The War Hound and the World's Pain_).

Comment: While a cat shows up regularly, there is no long-term mention of a cat's existence as part of the Eternal cycle or the Eternal Champion. Sometimes a cat is just a cat. When I wrote RPG material about Elric and the Eternal Champion Saga, Chaosium dissected the material quite thoroughly. The Eternal Feline was not one of the tropes, at best we could imagine is was a playful Chaos god who manifested regularly to watch the Eternal Champion struggle.

Comment: While the many incarnations of the Eternal Champion is necessary for the many incarnations of the battle between Law and Chaos in the multiverse, I'm not sure the Cosmic Balance would deem it necessary to create an Eternal Champion's Eternal House Pet.